# echo $xml_data->asXML(); outputs nothing

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

Here is a (very) simplified PHP file that illustrates the problem (including the XML I'm using):

```
<?php
$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('http://www.americanhistoryusa.com/wp-content/campaign_trail/election_map_2012.xml', NULL, TRUE);
print_r($xml_data); //Outputs expected XML data in print_r
echo $xml_data->asXML(); //Outputs absolutely nothing
?>
```

- I am 1000% sure that $xml_data is a simpleXML object
- I've seen the same syntax for using $xml_data->asXML(); in about 20 different places.
- I'm using PHP version 5.2.17 if that entails any potential compatibility/deprecation issues?

What could be going wrong here? All I want it to do is echo the $xml_data in standard text form.

Comment: works for me... (PHP 5.3.8 and 5.3.3)

Comment: works for me too, with PHP 5.3.10.

Comment: I had checked with 5.3.15 and 5.2.14 and it works fine

Comment: let me guess, you try to access it from the web and see a blank page ? try to "view source"...

Comment: Interesting. alfasin you are correct

Answer (score 4):

`// Outputs absolutely nothing` is just because you check it in the browser, the browser won't display the xml content for you. (You could check the html source, there it is.)

Or if you want to display it in the browser, try

```
echo "<pre>".htmlentities($xml_data->asXML())."</pre>";
```

Comment: Or output as a content type that you *can* see. `ini_set('default_mimetype', 'text/plain')` or `header('Content-Type:text/plain')`.

Comment: Thank you much for the help. I didn't realize this data would be present but invisible when I called that method. It's doing what I want it to now.